# Get enterprise application permissions

Tags: azure

I need to get all permissions of enterprise application.
I did manages to get 'Delegated type' with [oauth2PermissionGrants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but not the 'Application'.
[image: here is what I'm talking about]

How can I get them from REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application permissions are appRoles within the API, so you can get those through the appRoleAssignments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

```
GET /servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignments
```